# SQL-Server and MySQL interoperability?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

We're going from a SQL-Server 2008 backend to a MySQL backend.  What's the interoperability between SQL-Server and MySQL?

Will we be able to run SQL Queries that reference tables from databases across the servers?

For example, is this possible:  *pseudo code*

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
      [SQL2008Server].[databaseA].[DBO].[table1] as t1 
  INNER JOIN 
      [MySQLServer].[databaseB].[dbo].[table2] as t2 
          ON t1.id = t2.fkid
```

If not, what options can you recommend for integrating data across SQL-Server 2008 and MySQL?

Would LINQ provide any relief in regards to combining data from SQL-Server and MySQL?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to add a MySQL server into SQL Server as a linked server.

- [HOWTO: Setup SQL Server Linked Server to MySQL](http://www.ideaexcursion.com/2009/02/25/howto-setup-sql-server-linked-server-to-mysql/)

Once you have set it up you can query using OPENQUERY like this:

```
SELECT t1.colA, t2.colB
FROM SQLdbName.dbo.tablename AS t1
INNER JOIN OPENQUERY(MySQLlinkedservername, 
                     'SELECT colA, colB FROM tablename') AS t2
ON t1.colA = t2.colA
```

Comment: Mark...thank you!  That was exactly what I was looking for!  This worked beautifully!

The sql examples in the tut were a little wonky.  So, for anyone searching for it heres an example sql JOIN between our SQL2008Server and MySQLServer:

SELECT t1.colA, t2.colB FROM SQLdbName.dbo.tablename as t1 INNER JOIN OPENQUERY(MySQLlinkedservername, 'SELECT colA, colB FROM tablename') as t2 ON t1.colA=t2.colA

Comment: @s15199d: Thanks for the comment. I put your SQL from the comment into my answer so that it is easier for others to read. Hope that's OK.