# Perform a JOIN between SQLite and MySQL using PDO in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sqlite

Is this at all possible? Or would it be necessary to perform individual queries against each DB, and then process the result in code or a tmp db table or whatever?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2 different servers then you **can not** couple these servers in a way that the data can be joined.

You need to execute the queries seperately on the servers and process the data later. It is possible to link a [SQL Server with other systems](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10227686/sql-server-and-mysql-interoperability) though.